# How to obtain BluetoothGatt object from RxAndroidBle

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243766/rxandroidble-can-connect-to-peripheral-but-standard-android-cant?noredirect=1#comment87539215_50243766), I have a legacy app that refuses to connect to one of the peripherals I'm trying to support (works OK with others). `RxAndroidBle` connects successfully too, and I'm thinking to use it just to establish the connection and hand it to the rest of the app. I need to get the `BluetoothGatt` object from the `RxBleConnection`; how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After careful study of the docs, I hope I have gotten this right. The extensive comments are for my own benefit but perhaps they will help others trying to understand this. Comments & corrections welcome.

```
public class GetGattOperation implements RxBleCustomOperation<BluetoothGatt> {

    private BluetoothGatt gatt;

    // How this may work:

    // You call rxBleConnection.queue( <instance of this class> )
    // It returns an Observable<T>--call it Observable A

    // The queue manager calls the .asObservable() method below,
    // which returns another Observable<T>--Observable B
    // It is placed in the queue for execution

    // When it's time to run this operation, ConnectionOperationQueue will
    // subscribe to Observable B (here, Observable.just( bluetoothGatt ))

    // Emissions from this Observable B (here, the bluetoothGatt) are forwarded to the Observable A returned by .queue()

    // Instances can be queued and received via a subscription to Observable A: 
    // rxBleConnection.queue( new GetGattOperation() ).subscribe( gatt -> {} );

    @Override
    public @NonNull Observable<BluetoothGatt> asObservable( BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt,
                                                            RxBleGattCallback rxBleGattCallback,
                                                            Scheduler scheduler) throws Throwable {

        gatt = bluetoothGatt;
        return Observable.just( bluetoothGatt );  // return Observable B
    }


    public BluetoothGatt getGatt( ) {
        return gatt;
    }

}
```

The main program uses this like so (in the `.establishConnection()` operator chain):

```
.doOnNext( connection -> {
    rxBleConnection = connection;
    connection.queue( new GetGattOperation() )  // queue() returns Observable A
        .subscribe( gatt -> {  // receives events forwarded from Observable B
            Log.i( "Main", "BluetoothGatt received: " + gatt.toString() );
        } );
    } 
)
```

Comment: This is also available as a Gist: https://gist.github.com/RobLewis/fc20bde8ce71c7da2040d04b2ba3c156

Comment: Hi @Robert Lewis I'm trying use `RxBleCustomOperation` to set native callback `rxBleGattCallback.setNativeCallback` but I don't understand well, could you give me an example please?

Comment: First of all, did you see the Javadoc for the `RxBleGattCallback` class? It recommends against using native callbacks except in performance-critical applications.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only option to obtain an instance of `BluetoothGatt` is to implement a `RxBleCustomOperation` interface and use it on the `RxBleConnection.queue(RxBleCustomOperation)`

```
public interface RxBleCustomOperation<T> {

  /**
   * (...)
   */
  @NonNull
  Observable<T> asObservable(BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt,
                             RxBleGattCallback rxBleGattCallback,
                             Scheduler scheduler) throws Throwable;
}
```

Be mindful about the Javadoc on both the `RxBleCustomOperation` interface and on the `RxBleConnection.queue(RxBleCustomOperation)` function.